# How to remove "Create: option in search view opened after clicking Search view in odoo 8?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

How to remove the create option that appears in "search more" view. 
[image: Search More]

[image: Create option]

I tried with no_create and few things,  but did not help. Anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**many2one widget (default)**

**Options** : Other possible options you can use with this widget.

- no_quick_create - remove the Create and edit... option.
- no_create_edit - remove the Create "search_value" option.
- no_create - no_quick_create and no_create_edit combined.
- no_open - in read mode: do not render as a link.

**Example:**

```
<field name="field_name" options="{'no_quick_create': True,    'no_create_edit' : True}"/>
```

**Many2many**

1. **widget (default)**

   **Options**

   ```
   - no_create - remove the “Create” button.
   ```

   **Example**

   ```
   <field name="field_name" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
   ```
2. **many2many_tags widget**

   **Options**

   `no_quick_create - remove the Create and edit... option.`

   `no_create_edit - remove the Create "search_value" option.`

   `no_create - no_quick_create and no_create_edit together.`

   **Example**

   ```
   <field name="field_name" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_create_edit': True}"/>
   ```

> In order to remove CREATE button from search popup, you need to remove
>   it from ~/web/static/src/xml/base.xml file
>
> there is code which add this button into that search wizard. This
>   button is adding conditionally to the wizard but `no_create:True` is
>   not working somehow. So if you want to remove it from every wizard
>   then just remove it from file else think something how to hide that
>   field conditionally.

```
<t t-name="SelectCreatePopup.search.buttons">
    <t t-if="! widget.options.disable_multiple_selection">
        <button type="button" class="oe_button oe_selectcreatepopup-search-select oe_highlight" disabled="disabled">Select</button>
    </t>
    <t t-if="!widget.options.no_create">
    <button type="button" class="oe_button oe_selectcreatepopup-search-create">Create</button>
    or </t><a class="oe_selectcreatepopup-search-close oe_bold oe_form_button_cancel" href="javascript:void(0)">Cancel</a>
</t>
```

Comment: Emipro Technologies, First of all thank you for your valueable answer, Create and edit disappears in the many2one field, but I wanted the create button to be disappeared in the search view i.e after clicking search more, a search view opens , in that search view(that is the second picture).

Comment: Review updated answer, I have added few more contents into that.

Comment: Excellent Emipro Technologies, Spot on. Thanks for the valueable answer. Thank you very much... Great help...

Comment: In (2), I think you have the `no_quick_create` and `no_create_edit` definitions mixed up.  `no_quick_create` removes "create" and `no_create_edit` removes "create and edit".

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me, I did a little change:

```
init: function(parent, options) {
    this._super(parent, options);

    _.defaults(this.options, { initial_view: "search" });
    this.initial_ids = this.options.initial_ids;
if(parent.options && (parent.options.no_create_edit || parent.options.no_create)){
        this.options.no_create = true;
}

},
```